# Terminal.Gui keeping text within bounds

Tags: c#, user-interface, terminal.gui

I'm using the terminal.gui library for c#. The text currently runs off the edge of the frame, but I want it to start a new line when it reaches the edge.
Here is my code (frame 1 code not inlcuded since its not relevant):

```cs
            Application.Init();
            var top = Application.Top;
            var mainWindow = new Window("The")
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 1,
                Width = Dim.Fill(),
                Height = Dim.Fill(),
            };
            var frame1 = new FrameView();
            frame1.Width = Dim.Percent(30, false);
            frame1.Height = Dim.Fill();
            frame1.Title = "Archives";
            mainWindow.Add(frame1);

            var frame2 = new FrameView();
            frame2.Width = Dim.Percent(70, false);
            frame2.Height = Dim.Fill();
            frame2.X = Pos.Right(frame1);
            frame2.Title = "Viewer";
            mainWindow.Add(frame2);

            top.Add(mainWindow);
            Label lbl = new Label("helllllllo world helllllllo world helllllllo world ");
                        lbl.Width = 10;
                        frame2.Add(lbl);
```

here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your label has a vertical height of 1 (the default height).  If you change its Height and Width to `Dim.Fill()` then it will automatically wrap:

```cs
lbl.Width = Dim.Fill();
lbl.Height = Dim.Fill();
```

If you do that then it will look something like this:

[image]

**Note**: If you want scrolling and other features then you might want to change from `Label` to `TextView`:

```cs
TextView lbl = new TextView();
lbl.Text = "helllllllo world helllllllo world helllllllo world ";
lbl.WordWrap = true;
lbl.Width = Dim.Fill();
lbl.Height = Dim.Fill();
lbl.ReadOnly = true;
```